# Get lastest release version from Artifactory Generic repository

Tags: artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli

I'm working with several repositories, but now I need to download the lastest version of some artifacts from a generic repository. Following wiki instructions I created a new layout like this.
[Layout description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWiSw.png)

After that, I have added a new repository with this layout and deployed several artifacts according the layout as you can see.
[Artifacts in repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ncZ.png)

So, according this documentation: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout

I expected to download the latest version using this:

http://my-artifactory/distributable-example/OrgExample/moduleX/[RELEASE]/installer/example1-[RELEASE].exe

Instead of that I only get a 404 error. So, how can I get the lastest version?

Comment: It looks the file name has an extra dash sign at the end, just before the extension, which fails the pattern - example1-0.0.2-.exe

Comment: Thanks for seeing the error, but that not the problem, because after fix the layout, and upload some artifacts again the result is the same.